# Zeroth chapter and float numbering

Tags: floats, numbering, chapters, counters, newfloat

Consider the following document that tests the `newfloat` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    within = chapter,
    fileext = dia,
    listname = {List of Diagrams},
    name = {Diagram},
    placement = p,
]{diagram}
\captionsetup[diagram]{
    labelfont={small,bf},
    textfont={small},
}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{diagram}[!h]
\begin{center}
\textbf{\textsc{DIAGRAM}}
\end{center}
\caption{This is meant to be a diagram.}
\end{diagram}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{diagram}[!h]
\begin{center}
\textbf{\textsc{DIAGRAM}}
\end{center}
\caption{This is meant to be a diagram.}
\end{diagram}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{diagram}[!h]
\begin{center}
\textbf{\textsc{DIAGRAM}}
\end{center}
\caption{This is meant to be a diagram.}
\end{diagram}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The numbering of diagrams is correct starting at chapter `1` (Diagram `1.1`, `2.1`...). However the diagram of chapter `0` is numbered `Diagram 1` instead of `Diagram 0.1`.

**How to make the numbering format `Diagram 0.1` for chapter `0`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to redefine manually the behavior of the counter instead of doing it with the `within` key of `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext = dia,
    listname = {List of Diagrams},
    name = {Diagram},
    placement = p,
]{diagram}
\captionsetup[diagram]{
    labelfont={small,bf},
    textfont={small},
}
\renewcommand{\thediagram}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{diagram}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{diagram}[!h]
\begin{center}
\textbf{DIAGRAM}
\end{center}
\caption{This is meant to be a diagram.}
\end{diagram}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{diagram}[!h]
\begin{center}
\textbf{DIAGRAM}
\end{center}
\caption{This is meant to be a diagram.}
\end{diagram}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{diagram}[!h]
\begin{center}
\textbf{DIAGRAM}
\end{center}
\caption{This is meant to be a diagram.}
\end{diagram}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Given the usernames for 2 seconds, I wondered: wait did I just answer myself and forgot about it... Btw, thanks, that works!

Comment: @Vincent When I saw your question I just _had_ to answer because of that confusion :^)